# Store address of Object in Windows Registry

Tags: windows, data-structures, registry

Can we store the the **address of the Object** in windows Registry and *later from some other function read the address we've stored* and **make changes in that Object directly**.

If it is possible, any pointers to getting started tutorial ..!

Comment: I strongly suspect that you're not asking the right question. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* store the address of an object in the registry and then come back later, read it, and then modify the object. For example in C you could have a pointer, convert it to a `long`, and store it in the registry:

```
SomePointer *p;
long i = (long)p;
// now store i in the registry
```

And later, get it back:

```
int new_i = read value from registry
SomePointer *new_p = (SomePointer *)i;
```

You really don't want to do that, though.

First, that pointer is only valid for the current instance of the program. If you exit the program and restart, then the pointer is no good. In addition, the pointer will be meaningless to any other application that might be running at any time. Also, in a garbage collected environment that can move things around in memory, the pointer could become invalid at any time.

Also, there's a performance impact. Accessing the registry is very slow.

From a software construction standpoint, it's really bad form to use a global resource such as the registry to solve the local problem of sharing data in a single program.

And, finally, from a practical standpoint, it makes no sense. If you have access to the source code so that you can modify it to write and read the registry, then you can use a more robust and less intrusive way to share the data. For example, the module that writes the registry could instead just export a symbol, and the module that you would have had reading the registry can access that exported symbol.

So, yes ... it is possible to store a pointer in the registry, and later read it back and access the object to which the pointer refers. But it's a really bad idea.